# fillRect() not overlapping exactly when float numbers are used

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

The following code ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3qjn9c6/)) draws a red square at random points on a canvas taking care to erase the previous one (by filling a white square over it with `ctx.fillRect()`:

```
<html>
  <canvas id='canvas' width=300 height=300/>
 <script>
   const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
   let prevRect = null;
   for (let i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
     if (prevRect != null) {
       ctx.fillStyle='white';
       ctx.fillRect(prevRect.x, prevRect.y, 50, 50);
     }
     ctx.fillStyle='red';
     const newRect = {x: Math.random()*(300-50), y: Math.random()*(300-50)};
     ctx.fillRect(newRect.x, newRect.y, 50, 50);
     prevRect = newRect;
   }
  </script>
</html>
```

The code fails to completely erase the previous square and artifacts remain on the screen. If, instead, I do the following:

```
const newRect = {x: Math.floor(Math.random()*(300-50)), y: Math.floor(Math.random()*(300-50))};
```

... then everything works as intended.

My question is why. It seems totally unnecessary that I have to truncate as I keep the values in the `prevRect` so the two calls to `fillRect()` use exactly the same coordinates (even when using floats) and so the two squares should always perfectly align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the basic way that things are drawn on a canvas. When you draw a square, the edges of the shape are slightly "feathered". Thus when you draw the white box over the previous red box, the remnants of red bleed into the semi-transparent edge.

If you draw 10 white boxes instead of one, the problem goes away. Or if you make the white box probably 0.5 pixels larger, that would likely help.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
   let prevRect = null;
   for (let i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
     if (prevRect != null) {
       ctx.fillStyle='white';
       ctx.fillRect(prevRect.x - 0.75, prevRect.y - 0.75, 51.5, 51.5);
     }
     ctx.fillStyle='red';
     const newRect = {x: Math.random()*(300-50), y: Math.random()*(300-50)};
     ctx.fillRect(newRect.x, newRect.y, 50, 50);
     prevRect = newRect;
   }
```

```css
body, html { padding: 0; }

canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas height=300 width=300></canvas>
```

Looks like 0.75 bigger on each side works pretty well, but it's certain to be a function of canvas "logical" size vs. actual screen size.

Comment: could you perhaps supply a link that describes this "feathering"? I had assumed that `fillRect()` simply truncates the floats internally to do its work. I was also not aware that a rectangle I draw on canvas had an "semi-transparent edge".

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus I'll see if I can find a reference, but the basic idea is that the "size" of the canvas is the *conceptual* size. The browser maps that onto the actual screen pixel size, so floating point or not there's always likely to be some fuzzy edges.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus consider that when you draw a line from A to B, the stroke width is on either side of the line. If the stroke width is 1, then the line spreads 0.5 pixels on either side of the geometric (zero-width) line between the points. Drawing on a canvas is not as simple as one might first assume.

Comment: I can see why complications would arise with diagonals but I had assumed that for rectangular shapes and horizontal / vertical lines everything is crisp. But then you are indeed right that the canvas conceptual dimensions have to map onto actual pixels. It would seem then that there is no way to precisely "erase" (by overlapping with white) a previously drawn shape unless the entire canvas is cleared and redrawn. This makes animations where a single shape moves across the canvas (and we know that it's not going over other shapes) needlessly costly as we have to redraw everything.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus there are many things about the way the canvas feature works that make my head hurt, but what can you do

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus on the other hand, the facility is incredibly fast on modern browsers (and modern computers).

Answer (score 2):

### How do you render half a pixel red?

By taking the background color and interpolating with the foreground color based on the percentage, how much the foreground overlaps the background.
When you now try to "delete" that, you do the same with the background-color.

So mathematically the color of the pixel is:

```
var afterRender = interpolate(background, forground, percentage);
var afterDelete = interpolate(afterRender, background, percentage);
```

let's crunch some numbers: *(a quick and dirty example)*

```js
const update = () => {
  var bgColor = +bg.value.replace(/^#?/, "0x");
  bg.style.backgroundColor = toColor(bgColor);
  
  var fgColor = +fg.value.replace(/^#?/, "0x");
  fg.style.backgroundColor = toColor(fgColor);
  
  var percentage = overlap.value / 100;

  var afterRenderColor = interpolate(bgColor, fgColor, percentage);
  
  afterRender.textContent = afterRender.style.background = toColor(afterRenderColor);
  
  // now trying to erase this by overwriting with the background-color
  var afterDeleteColor = interpolate(afterRenderColor, bgColor, percentage);
  
  afterDelete.textContent = afterDelete.style.background = toColor(afterDeleteColor);
}

const toColor = v => "#" + v.toString(16).padStart(6, 0).toUpperCase();

const interpolate = (a, b, t) => ((a&0xFF0000) * (1-t) + (b&0xFF0000) * t) & 0xFF0000
    | ((a&0x00FF00) * (1-t) + (b&0x00FF00) * t) & 0x00FF00
    | ((a&0x0000FF) * (1-t) + (b&0x0000FF) * t) & 0x0000FF;


[bg, fg, overlap].forEach(input => input.onchange = input.oninput = update);
update();
```

```css
#bg,
#fg,
#afterRender,
#afterDelete {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label>Background: <input id="bg" type="text" pattern="/#?[0-9a-f]{6}/" value="#FFFFFF"/></label>
<br>
<label>Foreground: <input id="fg" type="text" pattern="/#?[0-9a-f]{6}/" value="#FF0000"/></label>
<br>
<label>"half a pixel" of overlap: <input id="overlap" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50"></label>
more or less ;)

<br>
<br>

Color after rendering "half a pixel" of the foreground over the background:
<div id="afterRender"></div>

<br>
Color after trying to erase that by rendering "half a pixel" of the background-color over that:
<div id="afterDelete"></div>
```

Comment: This answer is promising! Could you explain why the second interpolate would not use the background, though? I would have written:
```var afterDelete = interpolate(background, newForeground, percentage);```

Comment: because, after rendering the foreground, this pixel does no longer have the background color. If the pixel still contains the background-color, this means one of two things: 1. Foreground and background have the same color at this point, or 2. foreground is 100% transparent at this point. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: So you call "background" the color of the pixel before it is changed, is that it ? I would have thought, by the name of it, that it were the general background color.

Where can I get more info on how and when the interpolation you're talking about is done exactly in JS ? I still feel that I miss the whole picture...

Comment: I call `background`, the color of the pixel before it is changed, I call `foregound` the color of the shape I'm rendering, and after rendering the FG onto the BG, I try to erase it by rendering the very same shape with the BG color on top of that.