# Javascript - Erasing a circle in Canvas by re-drawing it in white

Tags: javascript, canvas

This is a comprehension question only.

1. I fill a black circle.
2. I fill a white circle exactly over it.
3. I would have expected to see nothing, but yet I see a very thin black circle. Why ? What happens ?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle="black";
ctx.arc(50, 50, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);            
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.arc(50, 50, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);   
ctx.fill();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a4fuLbgk/1/

Comment: anti-aliasing is probably the culprit here. just increase the mark circle size or add a stroke to it and it will cover the black circle.

Comment: this is the same Problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136632/fillrect-not-overlapping-exactly-when-float-numbers-are-used/58137425#58137425

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by painting the stroke as well.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle="black";
ctx.arc(50, 50, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);            
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.strokeStyle="white"
ctx.arc(50, 50, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.stroke()
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: The question is "why" not how to fix it. And this solution doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/en3j08pq/

Comment: @Kaiido This solution works. why do you repaint image and said it doesn't work. `https://jsfiddle.net/agLh1b0n/`. You have to know that In canvas painting, the order of painting matters.

Comment: (*cough!*). The fiddle demonstrates that your solution doesn't convert all the painted pixels to white. What it does is apply your solution, then search for all pixels that are not white and make these solid red to expose how your code fails. If your code did work, then at l15 all pixels would have been white (0xFFFFFFFF) and there wouldn't be any red pixels from my addition.