# Unpredictable behaviour of HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I observe weird behaviour of HTML canvas both in chrome and in firefox. For some reason there is one-pixel wide palid line when I fill rect over the smaller rect of different color after clipping.

Here is JS fiddle snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/srkgbxw1/7/

```
var my_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = my_canvas.getContext("2d");

context.translate(0.5, 0.5)

context.fillStyle = "orange";
context.fillRect(10,10,100,100);

context.beginPath();
context.rect(20,20,90,90);
context.clip();

context.fillStyle = "white";
context.fillRect(0,0,110,110);

context.fillStyle = "orange";
context.fillRect(0,0,190,190);
```

This is the result:
[image]

Please help me figure out what the reason for the pallid line after third fillRect with orange?

**UPD**: original question's changed after I was pointed out I had made a stupid mistake in its first edition

**UPD 2** I got the answer, this happens due to color interpolation at edges of clipping region because context was translated for half a pixel, which was done to get thin lines (recommended technique). To avoid interpolation, clipping region should be adjusted for half a pixel as well, then the pallid line disappears.

Comment: remove the `context.translate` line

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the logs:

```
TypeError: context.setStrokeStyle is not a function
```

Therefore, when you comment it, everything after it is executed while when you uncomment it, it fails and everything after this line is not executed.

EDIT: For the second question issue:

The issue is equivalent to this, why the blue square does not fully overlap the red square:

```
context.translate(0.5, 0.5);

context.fillStyle = "red";
context.fillRect(10,10,100,100);
context.fillStyle = "blue";
context.fillRect(10,10,100,100);
```

Because of translate, you are now drawing in float pixels, everything moved by half a pixel.
I suggest you read this for more information about how it is handled:
[fillRect() not overlapping exactly when float numbers are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136632/fillrect-not-overlapping-exactly-when-float-numbers-are-used)

Removing `context.translate(0.5, 0.5);` removes the "palid line".

Comment: Yes, Indeed! I feel stupid now :) Then, could please explain where is this palid line from? Why it is not cleared by second fillRect with orange?

Comment: @vvk What are you trying to get exactly? You are overlapping several rects one after the other. Everything is drawn in the order of the code.

Comment: I am trying to understand why white rect (fillRect #2 ) is not fully destroyed by fillRect (#3) - there is a palid line which should not be there according to my expectations

Comment: @vvk After some checking, I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know that thranslation matters in this example, but I do not understand why - looks like interpolation applies to borders of clipping region, which does not seem correct. P.S. I use this half pixel translation as recommended technique to get thin lines. I am now working on complicated drawings with overlaying regions and cannot achieve what I need :( Any way, thank you for your help